# After dragging I get incorrect coordinates of all the elements but the first

Tags: javascript, jquery, draggable

There are some div elements on my page. A user can drag any of them many times. After every dragging, I need to get new coordinates of the div that was dragged.

My code works good with div[0]: I actually get new coordinates after every new dragging.
The problem is with all the other divs, like div[1], div[2], div[10]... Script gets coordinates after the first dragging, but all the next times coordinates are still the same. They don't change.

I tried to clear variables, but that didn't help.

What could be this problem caused by? What should I check to find the solution?

I use jQuery and jQuery UI. Code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
$(".rD").draggable({
stop: function(event, ui) { 
// get the index of the dragged element 
id = $(this).index();
// get coordinates of the dragged element
rect = document.getElementsByTagName("div")[id].getBoundingClientRect();
alert("top:" + rect.top + ", left: " + rect.left);
// clearing variables didn't help to solve the problem
delete rect;
delete id;
}
});
```

Comment: did you check the jqueryui draggable api.. it mentions that the ui object will give you original and current positions.. which means that you can calculate the exact positions if required..

Comment: strange codestyle: creating global variables and deleting them. There are side effects anyway. What if somebody use global `id` variable? You clear it.

Comment: Maybe your `$(this).index()` is always `0`. Check what is `this`: draggable element or whole container?

Answer (score 0):

Try to:

```
alert(ui.position.top, ui.position.left)
```

[Documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#event-stop)

Whole code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
  $(".rD").draggable({
    stop: function(event, ui) { 
      // Use var keyword for your local variables
      // var rect = ui.helper[0].getBoundingClientRect();
      alert("top:" + ui.position.top + ", left: " + ui.position.left);
    }
  });
});
```